# Get Next Page Value in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvUserManage.Rows) {
    index = (int)gvUserManage.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
    bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkResume")).Checked;
    if (result) {
        Approve_UserId_y = index;
    }
    else {
        Approve_UserId_n = index;
    }
}
```

I am using `Gridview` with paging of 10 per page.
I need to get all values in the grid view depends on `checkbox` check using datakeys. In the above code, I got only the first page value.
How will I got all rows in `gridview`?

Comment: You don't try adding a `DataPager` on your GridView?

Comment: Users will not be able to change the checkboxes of those they cannot see, so the values will remain unchanged.